# How to access data from one component to another in angular in satisfying certain conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-components, viewchild

I have two components(member component and profile component).
And my requirement is to hide the forward button in member component i.e

**member.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="(post.PostPositionClass === 'message left') && enableForward" class="text-right cursor-pointer">
                                    <i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
                                    Forward
                                </div>
```

But I have to follow the conditions  to hide the forward button from another component that is profile component

**profile.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label account-label">Coaching Eligibility</label>
      <p *ngIf="!memberData.MemberProfile.IsPastProgramEndDate && 
     (this.settingData.IsCoachingEnabled || (this.settingData.CoachingModel === CoachingModelConstant.ConditionalCoaching))">
  <i class="fa fa-check green-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> Group is eligible</p>
   <p *ngIf="memberData.MemberProfile.IsPastProgramEndDate || !(this.settingData.IsCoachingEnabled || (this.settingData.CoachingModel === CoachingModelConstant.ConditionalCoaching))" >
  <i class="fa fa-times red-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> Group is not eligible</p>
  
 <div *ngIf="!memberData.MemberProfile.IsPastProgramEndDate && 
  (this.settingData.IsCoachingEnabled || (this.settingData.CoachingModel === CoachingModelConstant.ConditionalCoaching))">
  <p *ngIf="this.settingData.IsDoNotCoachEnabled" >
   <i class="fa fa-times red-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> Member not eligible
    </p>
 <p *ngIf="(!this.settingData.IsDoNotCoachEnabled)" class="green-color">
  <i class="fa fa-check green-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> Member is eligible
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

Now I have to hide the **forward** button with satisfying the two conditions those are Group is not eligible and Member not eligible (*for these two conditions I have to hide the forward button which is in profile component*).

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: ProfileComponent is a child of MemberComponent? Or is it the other way around? What have you tried so far? If you can make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) it is easyer to help you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a state service that you inject in both components and in which you set your state from profile component and read it to display conditionally your stuff in member component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).